# Android FireBase OnDataChange code not being permanant

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXBrG.png)
I get the followingg Toast outputs
CODE IS RUNNING
and
s
So my code is running but my_shop is not being changed?

Comment: yes, [that's how it works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working fine, I think you are a bit confused as to how the code above actually works. the `onDataChanged` method is triggered/called asynchronously **ONLY** when the data in the database/server changes, hence the toast-'CODE IS RUNNING' is displayed correctly.

But you are checking the `my_shop.getShop_name()` outside the `onDataChanged` method, hence by the time the program counter reaches the second toast, the `onDataChanged` method hasn't been called yet. The shop_name is still the one that you assigned in line 2 which is what is displayed on the Toast! (which is why you think the code isn't running properly even if it is working fine!)

I would suggest you read more about event listeners in general to get a better idea abouut this behaviour! you can read more about the API in the firebase documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write